# How to show just the first matched selector on click when there may be multiple identical selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of read more buttons with accompanying div content, unfortunately these read more and content divs cant be wrapped together so I was wondering what is the best way to display the correct content when a read more link is clicked, I've tried .closest and .next with no success.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/QJcFf/1/

**JS**

```
var readMore = $('.readmore');


readMore.on('click', function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

   var el = $(this);
    console.log(el);

   el.next('.more-ctn').show();
    console.log( el.closest('.more-ctn') );

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-content">
    <p>lorem ipsum <a href="#" class="readmore">Read more</a></p>

    <div class="more-ctn">
        <p>Content for first readmore</p>
    </div>

    <p>lorem ipsum <a href="#" class="readmore">Read more</a></p>

    <div class="more-ctn">
        <p>Content for first readmore</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace your following code:

```
el.next('.more-ctn').show();
```

for this one:

```
el.parent().next('.more-ctn').show();
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/QJcFf/2/)